# Can't change wifi settings

Tags: wifi

My wifi credentials have been changed but i can't change my raspi wifi connection. 
I can change it via the gui, but after a reboot, the old settings appear again in the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Tried to change if via nano and cli but after rebooting, the old settings are appearing again.

I also tried to copy the wpa_supplicant.conf file to wpa_supplicant.conf_old file but after rebooting the pi, the original file was there and the backup disappeared.

Can somebody please help me locating the real wifi settings file so my wpa_supplicant.conf is not rewritten again with the old settings?

Comment: How did you try to change it? All you have told us is what **didn't** work.

Comment: I tried both via cli and via the gui in the right topcorner what worked, but after a reboot or shutdown, internet is lost because the changes i made to the wifi configuration are lost again

Comment: `the pi, the original file was there and the backup disappeared` that is very unusual - what are you running? Raspbian?

Comment: Yes raspbian pixal on pi3 . I already did an apt-get update and upgrade. I have no idea how this can happen. Seems like during startup it reloads the same settings from a previous period. Also my datetime and timestamp are 2 months back in time. Until i set the wifi and it loads the correct time from the internet.

Comment: Follow this link: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74593/wifi-not-working-on-fresh-install/105799#105799

Comment: Just to be clear, are you editing the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, or are you editing the file `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed an extra network manager. No problem. Create a `/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf` file instead of the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file. and when you reboot you will see it changed.